# Create Eclipse Python project for ROS

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, ros

I want to create an Eclipse python project for ROS. I have been looking in ROS tutorials, ROS answers and stackoverflow but I have not seen an appropriate answer.

First of all, I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`, `ROS Indigo`, `Eclipse Neo`n and `Python 2.7`, even though I don't think that change anything with respect to previous versions on this specific topic.

The sequence of commands I follow to do that is:

```
mkdir -p ws/src
cd ws/src
catkin_create_pkg mypackage std_msgs rospy roscpp
cd ..
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
awk -f $(rospack find mk)/eclipse.awk build/.project > build/.project_with_env && mv build/.project_with_env build/.project
cmake ./src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cd src/mypackage
python $(rospack find mk)/make_pydev_project.py
mv .pydevproject ../../build
```

The questions are:

1. I prefer to do `catkin_make` than `catkin build` because the later one places .project in some subfolder within `/build`. Is that ok, or would you suggest to use `build` instead?
2. With `catkin_make --force ... no CMakeLists.txt` is generated at the workspace level, so I run `catkin_init_workspace` to create one. I cannot do it before because `catkin_make` would complain about the `CMakeLists`. Do you see any problem on that?
3. Do I have to run `awk -f $(rospack ... for the .pydevproject` as well?
4. As a result, I end up having a `.project` and `.pydevproject` in build. When I import the project in eclipse (Import existing project into Workspace), it is done as a C++ project. I have then to convert it to pydev project. Is that normal?
5. The list of libraries in the project is illustrated in the figure below. Anything missing? [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJwMY.png)
6. And the tree structure in Eclipse is shown in the next picture. As you can see,  it is quite a mess. Is it possible to clean it? [Eclipse Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnjN4.png)
7. To close up, I would like to ask whether there is a simpler way to get the job done.

Comment: I had a look.  Your question is if there's an easier way?

Comment: There are 7 questions, being only the last one about possibilities to make it easier. Anyhow, I edited question 1 to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a bit strange that they'd generate a `.pydevproject` and don't mark it such (which would be having a section in the `.project` with the contents below inside the `projectDescription` tag)

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.python.pydev.PyDevBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Note: I know about the PyDev side, but I have no idea what the actually generate in the `.project` and `.pydevproject` files... my suggestion would be opening those files and seeing what they contain to try to get your answers.

You can create an empty PyDev project with some folder added as a source folder by following the manual to know what's expected following the PyDev manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual.html and then compare what they generate to that one (it's a xml file with a pretty simple structure).